# Django recommendation engine only works via python shell

Tags: django, python-2.7, redis, recommendation-engine

I have written this recommendation engine(based on Django by Example Antonio Mele).

All works when tested using the shell, and the recommended products can been seen in the rendered templates. 
But when an order is completed via the application, recommendations are not created or displayed.

Am completely stuck on this one, any suggestions much appreciated....

```
import redis
from django.conf import settings
from .models import Product
# connect to redis
r = redis.StrictRedis(host=settings.REDIS_HOST,port=settings.REDIS_PORT,db=settings.REDIS_DB)
class Recommender(object):
    def get_product_key(self, id):
        return 'product:{}:purchased_with'.format(id)

    def products_bought(self, products):
        product_ids = [p.id for p in products]
        for product_id in product_ids:
            for with_id in product_ids:
                # get the other products bought with each product
                if product_id != with_id:
                    # increment score for product purchased together
                    r.zincrby(self.get_product_key(product_id),with_id,amount=1)
    def suggest_products_for(self, products, max_results=6):
        product_ids = [p.id for p in products]
        if len(products) == 1:  
            # only 1 product
            suggestions = r.zrange(self.get_product_key(product_ids[0]),0, -1, desc=True)[:max_results]
        else:
            # generate a temporary key
            flat_ids = ''.join([str(id) for id in product_ids])
            tmp_key = 'tmp_{}'.format(flat_ids)
            # multiple products, combine scores of all products
            # store the resulting sorted set in a temporary key
            keys = [self.get_product_key(id) for id in product_ids]
            r.zunionstore(tmp_key, keys)
            # remove ids for the products the recommendation is for
            r.zrem(tmp_key, *product_ids)
            # get the product ids by their score, descendant sort
            suggestions = r.zrange(tmp_key, 0, -1,desc=True)[:max_results]
            # remove the temporary key
            r.delete(tmp_key)
        suggested_products_ids = [int(id) for id in suggestions]
        # get suggested products and sort by order of appearance
        suggested_products = list(Product.objects.filter(id__in=suggested_products_ids))
        suggested_products.sort(key=lambda x: suggested_products_ids.index(x.id))
        return suggested_products
```

This is the PRODUCT Detail view

```
def product_detail(request, id, slug):
    language = request.LANGUAGE_CODE
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id, translations__language_code=language,
                                translations__slug=slug, available=True)
    cart_product_form = CartAddProductForm()
    r = Recommender()
    recommended_products = r.suggest_products_for([product])
    return render(request, 'shop/product/detail.html', 
        {'product': product, 'cart_product_form': cart_product_form, 
        'recommended_products': recommended_products })
```

THE CART VIEW

```
def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    for item in cart:
        item['update_quantity_form'] = CartAddProductForm(initial={'quantity': item['quantity'], 'update':True})

    coupon_apply_form = CouponApplyForm()
    r = Recommender()
    cart_products = [item['product'] for item in cart]
    recommended_products = r.suggest_products_for(cart_products)
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart,'recommended_products': recommended_products,'coupon_apply_form': coupon_apply_form })
```

THE SHOP ORDER VIEW

```
def order_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        r = Recommender()
        cart_products = [item['product'] for item in cart]
        recommended_products = r.suggest_products_for(cart_products,4)
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save(commit=False)
            order.save()

            if cart.coupon:
                coupon = cart.coupon
                coupon.save()
                order.discount = coupon.discount
                order.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(order=order, product=item['product'], price=item['price'], quantity=item['quantity'])

            #emptying the cart
            r = Recommender()
            cart_products = [item['product'] for item in cart]
            recommended_products = r.suggest_products_for(cart_products)
            cart.clear()
            #launch celery async task
            order_created.delay(order.id)
            request.session['order_id'] = order.id #set order.id session
            return redirect(reverse('payment:process'))
    else:

        form = OrderCreateForm()
        r = Recommender()
        cart_products = [item['product'] for item in cart]
        recommended_products = r.suggest_products_for(cart_products)
    return render(request, 'orders/order/create.html', {'cart': cart, 'form':form, 'recommended_products':recommended_products})
```

THE following HTML is added to the templates,

```
{% if recommended_products %}
<div class="recommendations">
<h3>{% trans "People who bought this also bought" %}</h3>
{% for p in recommended_products %}
<div class="item">
<a href="{{ p.get_absolute_url }}">
<img src="{% if p.image %}{{ p.image.url }}{% else %}{%static "img/no_image.png" %}{% endif %}">
</a>
<p><a href="{{ p.get_absolute_url }}">{{ p.name }}</a></p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging or adding some print at some points?

Comment: I have followed this course and have a problem! when I choose each product, it suggests just the first product, even when I choose the first product! I think it is because of this line in the recommender.py : suggestions = r.zrange(self.get_product_key(product_ids[0]), 0, -1, desc=True)[:max_results] Do you receive suggestions correctly? Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

The problem was that the porducts_bought() method needed to be invoked first

So the code in the cart_detail function changed

FROM

```
.......
    r = Recommender()
    cart_products = [item['product'] for item in cart]
    recommended_products = r.suggest_products_for(cart_products)
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart,'recommended_products': recommended_products,'coupon_apply_form': coupon_apply_form})
```

TO

```
........
    r = Recommender()
    cart_products = [item['product'] for item in cart]
    r.products_bought([item['product'] for item in cart])
    recommended_products = r.suggest_products_for(cart_products)
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart,'recommended_products': recommended_products,'coupon_apply_form': coupon_apply_form})
```